# NavigationView, как реализовать сдвиг тулбара и основного контента на право, при открытии бокового меню?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-view

Здравствуйте. Необходимо реализовать привязку тулбара и основного контента к правой границе бокового меню, чтобы при открытии бокового меню, весь экран как бы съезжал вправо. Уже прилично погуглил, но ничего вразумительного не нашел.Прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать SlidingPanelLayout для такого эффекта. Вот есть [пример](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial-2.html)